# Im making a calendar that can make room reservations and show projects milestones

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How can I put 2 events in the events so that it shows in the calendar the milestones and the reservations. Ive tried to put it like this:

```
events={milestones.map(milestone => {
                        return {
                            id: milestone.id,
                            title: milestone.description,
                            start: milestone.expectedDate
                        };
                    })/*, this.state.reservations*/}
```

By doing like this it only shows the milestones but if I put it like this:

```
events={/*milestones.map(milestone => {
                        return {
                            id: milestone.id,
                            title: milestone.description,
                            start: milestone.expectedDate
                        };
                    })*/ this.state.reservations}
```

It only shows the reservations. How can I put in a way that it shows both of them?

I tried to put it like this but it still only shows the first one:

```
events={milestones.map(milestone => {
                        return {
                            id: milestone.id,
                            title: milestone.description,
                            start: milestone.expectedDate
                        };
                    }) , this.state.reservations}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem!

```
events={[...milestones.map(milestone => ({
                            id: milestone.id,
                            title: milestone.description,
                            start: milestone.expectedDate
                        })), ...this.state.reservations]}
```